# Sequelize: query to include a parent model's data if it has associated children; don't return the child model's data

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

In my node.js app using sequelize with a postgresql database I have defined three models: users, baskets, and items. The users model has many baskets and baskets has many items.

I am trying to write a query to return the users and baskets only, without the items, if the basket contains one or more items. This query is getting me the data I need (users and baskets if the basket has items), but the problem with it is that it is also giving me all the items.

```
return await models.User.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: models.Basket,
      include: [{
        model: models.Item, 
        required: true
      }],
    }],
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need anything from items table,

```
return await models.User.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: models.Basket,
    include: [{
      attributes: [],    // <----- Add this line
      model: models.Item, 
      required: true
    }],
  }],
});
```